# How to pass azure app service principal id to SQL Server using terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-server

I have come across a situation, where i have to pass this {azurerm_app_service.app1.identity.0.principal_id to SQL Server inside User assigned managed identity? Any suggestion how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Managed identities is a **Microsoft Azure feature** that allows Azure resources to authenticate or authorize themselves with other supported Azure resources. You can use a system-assigned managed identity or a user-assigned managed identity (preview) in your case.

But terraform currently don't support the user-assigned managed identity for Microsoft SQL Azure Database Server. If you check the [**identity argument block**](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/mssql_server#identity) in this terraform document, you will find the following -

> An  `identity`  block supports `type` which specifies the identity
> type of the Microsoft SQL Server. At this time the only allowed value is  `SystemAssigned`.

So you can use the system-assigned managed identity with terraform now. Check this [terraform document](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/mssql_server) for more information.